# Lost connection to “my iPad”

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

Hi I am facing problem when loading a bunch of very large images (1772x1476 pixels) images from server using `SDWebImage` library

Actually I am loading and displaying this images on `UICollectionViewCell` using `SDWebImage` library

Problem after when I scroll `UICollectionView` up and down some time 
I am facing problem like my below image please help me why I am facing this problem and how can i resolve this

[image]

Comment: Your app crashed?Did you check if it overflowed?

Comment: after showing that window on xcode then app is automatically quitting

Comment: @Lumialxk do u know reason for this problem?